# unable to install React-native: Error msg warn Package expo contains invalid configuration: "dependency.platforms.ios.podspecPath"

Tags: react-native, installation, npx

I am attempting to re-install development environment after it became corrupted.
I am using Windows 10

Attempting to use npx react-native get the following error:

warn Package expo contains invalid configuration: "dependency.platforms.ios.podspecPath" is not allowed,"dependency.platforms.ios.project" is not allowed. Please verify it's properly linked using "react-native config" command and contact the package maintainers about this.

There may be fragments of the previous install in place, I do have projects I worked on previously still in place.

Any documentation on how to remove all elements of a previous install and start fresh?